# Oracle PL/SQL Update statement looping forever - 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a table based on another one's information:

Source_Table (Table 1) columns:
TABLE_ROW_ID (Based on trigger-sequence when insert)
REP_ID
SOFT_ASSIGNMENT

Description (Table 2) columns:
REP_ID
NEW_SOFT_ASSIGNMENT

This is my loop statement:

```
SELECT count(table_row_id) INTO V_ROWS_APPROVED FROM Source_Table; 

FOR i IN 1..V_ROWS_APPROVED LOOP

SELECT REQUESTED_SOFT_MAPPING   INTO V_SOFT    FROM Source_Table WHERE ROW_ID = i;
SELECT REP_ID                   INTO V_REP_ID  FROM Source_Table WHERE ROW_ID = i;

    UPDATE Description_Table D
    SET    D.NEW_SOFT_ASSIGNMENT = V_SOFT
    WHERE  D.REP_ID = V_REP_ID;

END LOOP;

END;
```

The ending result of this loop is a beautiful ''504 Gateway Time-out''.
I know the issue is on the Update query but there's no other way (I can think about) of doing it.
Can someone give me a hand please?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to run this block in a SQL client (SQL Developer, Toad, SQL*Plus etc) to see if you get a more helpful error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your `row_id` values are contiguous - i.e. count(row_id) == max(row_id) - then this will get a no-data-found. Sequences aren't gapless, so this seems fairly likely. We have no way of telling if that is happening and somehow that is leaving your connection hanging until it times out, or if it's just taking a long time because you're doing a lot of individual queries and updates over a large data set. (And you may be squashing any errors that do occur, though you haven't shown that.)

You don't need to query and update in a loop though, or even use PL/SQL; you can apply all the values in the source table to the description table with a single update or merge:

```
merge into description_table d
using source_table s
on (s.rep_id = d.rep_id)
when matched then
update set d.new_soft_assignment = s.requested_soft_mapping;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=804c3889bb61f92564199a22967d1988) with some dummy data, including a non-contiguous row_id to show that erroring.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Added MIN and MAX variables and it worked.